# Magento Related Products not showing

Tags: magento

this problem has been bugging me for a while now.

I have these simple products on my magento configuration at the moment. And I really like to make a related product for each of them. I was able to apply the filter and find the products itself on the back-end.

- My cache is disabled so this is not the problem
- I have re-indexed everything several times
- I checked if none of the items was added to the cart, but my cart was
  empty
- All the products are added to categories, have a quantity of > 0 and
  a "In Stock" property.

I have no idea why it is not displaying properly.

Comment: Anyone? :s I'm really stuck on this one :(

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

1. Login to Admin
2. Go to System -> Index Management
3. Select All checkboxes
4. Select 'Reindex Data' from Actions selection list
5. Click Submit button